# Nestjs guards error after using ClientModule

Tags: nestjs

I'm implementing Kafka and I used `ClientModule` imported from `@nestjs/microservices` inside my auth.module.ts file. When I comment this part

```
imports: [
        ClientsModule.register([
            {
                name: kafkaName,
                transport: Transport.KAFKA,
                options: {
                    client: {
                        clientId: kafkaName,
                        brokers: ['localhost:29092']
                    },
                    producerOnlyMode: true,
                    consumer: {
                        groupId: kafkaName
                    }
                },
            }
        ])
    ],
```

everything works fine but after uncommenting this part, I face with this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@nestjs/core/guards'
Require stack:
- /Users/mobinkazemi/Documents/codes/learn/kafkaGateway/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/microservices-module.js
- /Users/mobinkazemi/Documents/codes/learn/kafkaGateway/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/nest-microservice.js
- /Users/mobinkazemi/Documents/codes/learn/kafkaGateway/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/index.js
- /Users/mobinkazemi/Documents/codes/learn/kafkaGateway/dist/auth/auth.module.js
- /Users/mobinkazemi/Documents/codes/learn/kafkaGateway/dist/app.module.js
- /Users/mobinkazemi/Documents/codes/learn/kafkaGateway/dist/main.js
```

Here is my auth.module.ts file:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClientsModule, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

const kafkaName = 'auth_micro';

@Module({
    imports: [
        ClientsModule.register([
            {
                name: kafkaName,
                transport: Transport.KAFKA,
                options: {
                    client: {
                        clientId: kafkaName,
                        brokers: ['localhost:29092']
                    },
                    producerOnlyMode: true,
                    consumer: {
                        groupId: kafkaName
                    }
                },
            }
        ])
    ],
    providers: [AuthService],
    controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

Comment: I believe this is mismatch between `@nestjs/core` and `@nestjs/microservices`. Run `npx nest info`

Comment: I was getting same error Error: Cannot find module '@nestjs/core/guards' and @MicaelLevi solution solved my problem.